# Angular Auth "then" function content only executin in the second click

Tags: angular, typescript

im developing an angular web page but i don't know why the function called "changeValue()" only enters when i click it twice.

```
onRegister(): void {
    const user = {
      username: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      attributes: {
        email: this.email,
      }
    }
    
    Auth.signUp(user).then(async (data : any) => 
      this.changeValue(false)
    ).catch(err => {
      alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err))
    });
  }



 <div class="mt-3">
          <app-button (click)="onRegister()" buttonClass="btn w-100" text="REGISTER &#10140;"></app-button>
</div>
```

The "Auth" funtionality works correctly, the only problem is that the "changeValue" only runs the second time i clicked

Comment: The function `onRegister` is called too? What's the output? Furthermore, does the first call throw an error? Might be useful to add the template handling the click event as well.

Comment: When you press the button it calls correctly to onRegister() and executes Auth correctly (without any error throw). The only problem is that the function "changeValue" doesn't until i press the button for the second time (and calls Auth again) :S